# Enumerate over a Mutable Attributed String (Underline Button)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am trying to create a `UIButton` that allows the selected text to be underlined. This is my current code:

```
func underline() {
if let textRange = selectedRange {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    textView.textStorage.addAttributes([.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue], range: textRange)
    }
}
```

It is currently underlining but the problem I am having is that I need to check if the current text is underlined already and if it is remove the underline. I can't seem to work this out with the `NSMutableAttributedString`.

I am doing this with an Italic `UIButton` like so:

```
func italic() {
    if let textRange = selectedRange {
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
        attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: textRange, options: []) { (font, range, pointee) in
            let newFont: UIFont
            if let font = font as? UIFont {
                let fontTraits = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
                if fontTraits.contains(.traitItalic) {
                    newFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize, weight: .regular)
                } else {
                    newFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize).italic()
                }
                textView.textStorage.addAttributes([.font : newFont], range: textRange)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the ability to check if the current text has the underlining attribute for my first function?

Code we have so far:

```
func isUnderlined(attrText: NSAttributedString) -> Bool {
    var contains: ObjCBool = false
    attrText.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText.length), options: []) { (dict, range, value) in
        if dict.keys.contains(.underlineStyle) {
            contains = true
        }
    }
    return contains.boolValue
}

func underline() {
    if let textRange = selectedRange {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
        switch self.isUnderlined(attrText: attributedString) {
        case true:
            print("true")
            textView.textStorage.removeAttribute(.underlineStyle, range: textRange)
        case false:
            print("remove")
            textView.textStorage.addAttributes([.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue], range: textRange)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a text is already underlined, you can simply run **`contains(_:)`** on the attributes of the text, i.e.

```
func isUnderlined(attrText: NSAttributedString) -> Bool {
    var contains: ObjCBool = false
    attrText.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText.length), options: []) { (dict, range, value) in
        if dict.keys.contains(.underlineStyle) {
            contains = true
        }
    }
    return contains.boolValue
}
```

**Example:**

```
let attrText1 = NSAttributedString(string: "This is an underlined text.", attributes: [.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
let attrText2 = NSAttributedString(string: "This is an underlined text.", attributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFontSize])

print(self.isUnderlined(attrText: attrText1)) //true
print(self.isUnderlined(attrText: attrText2)) //false
```

You can use the above logic in your `UITextView` as per your requirement.

**To remove the attribute,**

**1.** first of all it must be an `NSMutableAttributedString`.

**2.** Then to remove an attribute, use `removeAttribute(_:range:)` method on attributed string.

```
let attrText1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is an underlined text.", attributes: [.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])

print(self.isUnderlined(attrText: attrText1)) //true
if self.isUnderlined(attrText: attrText1) {
    attrText1.removeAttribute(.underlineStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText1.string.count))
}
print(self.isUnderlined(attrText: attrText1)) //false
```

**Handle `textView` on button tap**

```
@IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let selectedTextRange = self.textView.selectedTextRange {
        let location = self.textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedTextRange.start)
        let length = self.textView.offset(from: selectedTextRange.start, to: selectedTextRange.end)
        let range = NSRange(location: location, length: length)

        self.textView.attributedText.enumerateAttributes(in: range, options: []) { (dict, range, value) in
            if dict.keys.contains(.underlineStyle) {
                self.textView.textStorage.removeAttribute(.underlineStyle, range: range)
            } else {
                self.textView.textStorage.addAttributes([.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue], range: range)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll make an if else with this function. How should I go about removing the attribute though?

Comment: Okay awesome, I had to change the first func (at: 0,) to 1 otherwise it's never calling the true part of the if statement... Is this correct?

Comment: Which `func` are your talking about? I don't understand.

Comment: The isUnderlined one.

Comment: `func (at: 0,) to 1` what is this? I've given you the generic code that you can use to solve your problem statement.

Comment: let attributes = attrText.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil).keys. I had to change 'at: 0' to 1 to allow the function to work. What is 'at: 0' referring to?

Comment: 0 is referring to the index you want to check for attributes in the `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to check for attributed in the whole range.

Comment: It's only working sporadically. It seems there's a bug somewhere. It will underline but on certain ranges is not removing the underline... Do I need to use an enumerate function instead of contains?

Comment: Try using that for detecting the attribute like you did for `italic()`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried. But it's not working. Do you know what to do with the EnumerateAttribute Function? I'm afraid I am doing the wrong thing :(

Comment: I've updated `isUnderlined()` with `enumerateAttributes`.

Comment: It still isn't working, it works for a bit then stops... Here is a recording to show you: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3549209f16a40153576aaf4ca412ed8e20190514080337/fa545a Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yep, just added :)

Comment: Updated the answer. I think this will solve your issue. Do accept and upvote if you get that working.

Comment: Got it working!!! Thanks heaps. What is the reason I have to manually set 'location, length then convert it to a NSRange? Why wasn't the native NSRange working?

Comment: `selectedTextRange` is of type `UITextRange` and not 'NSRange`. That's why the conversion was required.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird though. Because the 'selectedRange' var I was using before was a NSRange and even trying with it now it is producing the bug. It only is working when I have your code in that gets the UITextRange then converts it.